# Apache2 virtual hosts each on other disk is possible? hwo How to?

Tags: linux, virtual-host

My OS is Linux. I need configure Apache2 with virtual host, but each virtual host I need place on separate disk (first disk no enough space). Is it possible? If yes, please tell me how to do it?

Example:

path httpd.conf DocumentRoot is: /srv/www/htdocs/

first path vhost is: /srv/www/htdocs/www.firstvhost.com.ghi

second vhost path is: /srv/www/htdocs/www.secondvhost.com.ghi

I need:

www.firstvhost.com.ghi - all files on first SSD disk,
www.secondvhost.com.ghi - all files on second HDD disk.
Is it possible? May with symlinks - but I don't know ho to do it, please help and explain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just specifying the path you want to use for each virtual host in a VirtualHost section in `httpd.conf` for each host with a statement like `DocumentRoot /mnt/somedirectory/firsthost` Do you have a reason for needing to put each one under `/srv/www/htdocs/`?